# css padding on parent element shifts child position

Tags: css, position, parent-child, padding

Now I am absolutely confused.
I have created a little arrow (with css) nested inside a parent div that has overflow hidden with the idea in mind to move the arrow a little out at mouseover on its parent. 
The parent element is horizontally centered and for (some other) good reasons it has absolute positioning.

html:

```
<div id ="arrowContainer">
    <div id="arrow" class="arrow_left"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#arrowContainer {
    position: absolute;
    height: 54px;
    width: 13px;
    bottom: 4.2%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -9px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;    
}

.arrow_left {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 10px;
    right: -4px;
    border-top: 13px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
    border-right: 13px solid #fff;
    opacity: 0.72;
}
```

result:

[image]

Ok. Now I wanted that the mouseover area of the parent extends a little more to the sides. And I thought, well, use some padding. So I changed the parents CSS:

```
#arrowContainer {
    position: absolute;
    height: 54px;
    width: 13px;
    bottom: 4.2%;
    left: 50%;

    margin-left: -32px;
    padding: 0 24px;

    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;    
}
```

which leads to the more me unexpected result:

[image]

1) Not only that I had to encounter the padding in a new margin-left value, but ok, not so hard to do.

2) But why the hell my child with right: -4px value is positioned relative to the right of the padding and not the visible area (blue) of its parent any longer???

Ok. I know that I could use another container for both to fix this. But this I do not want! There must be a regular way to solve this with 2 divs only.
What is my mistake here? Thanks so much!

Comment: Try `right:20px` in the positioning for the arrow.

Comment: #arrowContainer { padding: 0 24px; }, this is pushing your arrow so much to the right, try using margin. A JSFiddle would be nice here.

Comment: try removing `right:-4px` http://jsfiddle.net/yggc3tfn/

Comment: Thanks guys! I see that the padding pushed the cild to the right. My question is: why?? I always thought that right refers to the right border of the div and not its padding edge. What sense has padding when it cannot be used this way?

Comment: padding is also considered as the `width` and `height` eg if you set a width of a div and add padding to the the width will increase

Comment: oops Thanks for clearing this for me! How would you add a wider mouseover area instead of using padding then? (in order to keep the positioning as it was.)

Answer (score 2):

> But why the hell my child with right: -4px value is positioned
>   relative to the right of the padding and not the visible area (blue)
>   of its parent any longer???

That's unfortunately how padding works. Padding adds space inside your element which moves the outer edges of your relative positioned element.

But there's is a solution. Instead of using top, bottom, left, right use **margin** to position your element.

When you add a element with the `position:absolute;` without setting any top, left, right or bottom position the element will be taken out of the normal flow. If you then position it by modifying its margins it will not get affected by the padding.

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/bowofejuzu/1/edit?html,css,output

HTML:

```
<div class ="container">
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position:relative;
  width:20px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#CCC;
  padding:0 40px;  
}

.element {
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color:red;

    margin: 40px 0 0 5px;
}
```

Comment: Ah. And I always thought that the padding is added OUTSIDE the element. Strange. Time to have learned that! And thanks guys also for the fiddles! What I felt was needed here was kind of an outside border. Maybe there is also a solution in this direction (keeping the top, bottom, left, right…) But so far thank you all very much!